# Autocompletion in utop

Tags: autocomplete, ocaml, utop

I am sorry for the newb question, but I am just starting with OCaml and I could not find how to ues utop autocompletion.

When I start typing something in utop, I see a list of choices at the bottom of the shell. If there is only one valid choice, pressing TAB will autocomplete what I am writing. But if there are multiple valid choices, and I spot the one I want, I have not found a way to select it (other than keep writing).

For instance (assuming I have imported `Core.Std`) I type

```
Float.of
```

The first suggestion is `Float.of_float`, the second one is `Float.of_int`. How do I select the second one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To quote utop's [README](https://github.com/diml/utop/blob/master/README.md):

> utop display a bar after the prompt which is used to show possible
>   completions in real-time. You can navigate in it using M-left and
>   M-right, and select one completion using M-tab. The M denotes the meta
>   key, which is Alt most of the time.

So, you can navigate through completions using `Alt`.

Have fun with utop!

EDIT:

It seems `Alt` doesn't always work, depending on the terminal. Typing `Esc` then the good keys, however, works.

Also, the bindings can be easily rebinded through a `~/.lambda-term-inputrc` file, see [here](https://github.com/diml/utop#key-bindings).

Comment: Actually, I had already tried all combinations of modifiers + arrow keys, but they do not work for me. In particular Alt+left and Alt+right do nothing on my system, while Win+left and Win+right are bound to window resizing (I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome shell). Any ways to rebind the keys?

Comment: (and by the way, using Alt+Tab to actually choose the completion is going to fail on every system I have tried - this is consistently used to switch between open windows)

Comment: Have you tried `Esc` then `arrow` or `Esc` then `tab`? `Esc` is often bound to put a `Meta` on the next key pressed, so that may solve it.

Comment: Right, Esc works! Still, I really would appreciate to be able to rebind keys in utop, as it is quite uncomfortable, especially given that I have to press Esc one time for each movement (that is, it does not behave as a modifier).

Comment: I added your useful feedback to my post. Thanks!

Comment: For macOS users: in Terminal.app, M-left/M-right are bound to escape sequences and won't work with utop. To unbind them, while running Terminal, go to Preferences (Command-,) -> Profiles -> Keyboard, select each one and click "-". It's good to make a new profile before doing this, in case you want to revert later. While you're on this page, select "Use Option as Meta key" too. After doing this, start a new Terminal with this profile, run utop, and now M-left/M-right will select different completions on the completion bar.

Comment: Btw, you can run `lambda-term-actions` command in your terminal to see the list of possible actions. You can also run `#utop_bindings;;` inside `utop` to see the current bindings

Comment: For Ubuntu: `Alt` + left - right to navigate and  `Alt + down` to select. `Tab` if there is only one suggestion.

Comment: fyi on macos, with iterm2, I have to press CMD + ALT (the apple key and left alt) with "Left option key" mapped to Esc+ in profiles -> keys in iterm's preferences